# How to solve the problem of using source mode docker to build project and create Oracle data source failure

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

Describe the question：
use source mode docker to build project and create Oracle data source failure.

Which version of DolphinScheduler:
-[apache-dolphinscheduler-incubating-1.3.4]

Additional context
Using official documents https://dolphinscheduler.apache.org/zh-cn/docs/1.3.4/user_ doc/docker- deployment.html After the building project is started (recommended) in docker-compose mode, the creation of Oracle11g data source will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the commercial license, we cannot directly use the driver and client of MySQL and Oracle. If you want to use Oracle, you can build a new image based on our apache/dolphinscheduler image.

Answer (score 0):

As for MySQL, you need to download mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar

Create your Dockerfile
FROM apache/dolphinscheduler:latest
COPY mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar /opt/dolphinscheduler/lib
RUN apk add --update --no-cache mysql-client
Build the image

As for Oracle in Datasource, you only need to download the Oracle driver and put it in the /opt/dolphinscheduler/lib directory